# R.java does not compile anymore after add Support V7 library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

After read A LOT of posts, googled for hours and tried everything I saw, I'm giving up and asking for help.

I have just one workspace with all of my projects and it is almost working fine, except because it is too slow. So I decide to split it in several workspaces by context.

Now I have my problem. I don't know why, but the same project that compile successfully using only one workspace, can't generate the R.java!

This example has google play service library and the android-support-v7-appcompat library. I have 515 error messages (R cannot be resolved to a variable)!

There are nothing in Console or Logcat. And of course I followed the [Support Library Setup instructions for libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#). I changed the target version to 19 in library and app, clean the projects a million of times... I'm really lost.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably don't mean workspace, I think you mean project. You split parts of your app out into separate library projects?

Comment: You should probably show an example of the type of error you are getting. Also, in the import section of your .java files there should be an `import com.myco.myapp.R` line. What does it say in your app?

Comment: I'm very shy about my mistake... I have a common project called rtcommon. I just forgot to import this project to my workspace and added the jar to build path. It was compiling like a charm, but never run. Because the basic project has resources, I must import the project. Thank's the help.